# jquery pagination refresh: pagining not remembering the changed styles in previous pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I am returning a list of items to view from controller.
in view am using a jquery a plugin for pagination to show the list in the pages.
The action method is

```
public ActionResult Messages()
{
    List<Message> listMessagesHeader = new List<Message>();
    listMessagesHeader.Add(new Message(){data="hi", isStared=false, MessageId=11});
    listMessagesHeader.Add(new Message(){data="hi", isStared=false, MessageId=0});
    listMessagesHeader.Add(new Message(){data="hi", isStared=false, MessageId=1});
    listMessagesHeader.Add(new Message(){data="hi", isStared=false, MessageId=2});
    listMessagesHeader.Add(new Message(){data="hi", isStared=false, MessageId=3});
    listMessagesHeader.Add(new Message(){data="hi", isStared=false}, MessageId=4);
    listMessagesHeader.Add(new Message(){data="hi", isStared=true}, MessageId=5);
    listMessagesHeader.Add(new Message(){data="hi", isStared=true}, MessageId=6);
    listMessagesHeader.Add(new Message(){data="hi", isStared=false}, MessageId=7);
    listMessagesHeader.Add(new Message(){data="hi", isStared=true}, MessageId=8);
    listMessagesHeader.Add(new Message(){data="hi", isStared=false}, MessageId=9);
    listMessagesHeader.Add(new Message(){data="hi", isStared=false}, MessageId=10);
    return View(listMessagesHeader);
}
```

My View looks like this

```
    @model List<Message>

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
    <title>Messages</title>
     <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Pagination.js")"></script>
   </head>
<body>
            <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
                <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding table">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-nowrap" id="content"  title="Inbox Messages">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>From</th>
                                <th>
                                    Subject
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <a href='#' title="Click Header to Sort">Date</a>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @if (Model != null)
                            {
                                foreach (var item in Model)
                                {

                                    <tr >

                                                @if(item.isStared){
                                                <td id="@item.MessageId">
                                                  <i   title="click to change importance" style="border-bottom: none ! important;" class="text-primary editable-click icon-star mark-star"></i>
                                                </td>
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                <td>
                                                 <i  title="click to change importance" style="border-bottom: none ! important;" class="text-primary editable-click icon-star-empty mark-star"></i>
                                                </td>
                                                }
                                                <td>
                                                   @Item.data
                                                </td>



                                            </tr>


                                }
                            }
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr id="pagerTwo">
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">
                                                <a href="#">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left prev pull-right"></span></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">
                                                <a href="#">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward first pull-right"></span></a>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="text" disabled class="pagedisplay col-xs-12 text-center" title="pagedisplay" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 pull-left">
                                                <a href="#"> <span class="next glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-left"></span></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">
                                                <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward last pull-left"></span></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <select class="pagesize" style="display: none" title="Pagesize">
                                        <option selected="selected" value="8">8</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="MessageBody" class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/TableScripts/jquery.tablesorter.Seccurepager.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pager = new Imtech.Pager();
        $(document).ready(function () {
            pager.paragraphsPerPage = 5; // set amount elements per page
            pager.pagingContainer = $('#content'); // set of main container
            pager.paragraphs = $('tr', pager.pagingContainer); // set of required containers
            pager.showPage(1);
        });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).on('click', '.mark-star', function () {
    $('#' + this.id).removeClass("icon-star-empty");
    $('#' + this.id).addClass("icon-star");
    debugger;
});

  </script>
```

I had written java script functions "AddStar" And "RemoveStar" functions to add remove icon for message.

the problem is due to the pagination script I am unable to persist the added style classes.
when I click next page and then on previous page. the previous page added styles classes are removed and page is shown in original form.

Comment: What is `Imtech.Pager()`?

Comment: Which pager initialization Metod in Pagination.js
Please Refer this https://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-create-easy-pagination-with-jquery/

Comment: When you go to a new page, your making a new request. The controller has no knowledge of what classes you have added/removed in a previous view. If you want to persist the data, you need to call a controller method to set the `isStared` property using ajax and save the value.

Comment: No iam not making new request on Page change to controller i am just arranging  the List in "#content"  to pages by using the JQuery paginator scirpt. @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

Remove those onclick event and user jquery click event like

```
$(document).on('click','#element',function(){

});
```

Actually when you change the page then your html gets refreshed and your defined onclick event lost so its better to use jquery event. those will work in every case.

And also it is not advised to use inline css. Use style classes so it can persist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
please check the updated question i changed as u mentioned but same thing is repeated the style  classes didn't persisted on changing pages.

Comment: are you talking about this class : icon-star-empty

Comment: yes i am replacing the class  icon-star-empty with icon-star and changing the pages the the class go back to its original postion

Comment: ok, gotcha.. actually when you click on paging... it reloads the whole html and removes your changes...